# Drools fire only those rules which names are configured in a file Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, drools

I had a Yml(I am okay with any extension ) file where I am storing all the rules' names. I need to fire all the names that are configured in this file. When I want to Disable a rule for execution I will just comment or I will remove that rule name in that file so that the rule will not be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce `EligibleRules` with `Set<String>` rules and make additional condition for each rule.

```
rule "Rule 1"
when
    EligibleRules(rules contains "Rule 1")
    ...
```

insert single copy of `EligibleRules` into the session, update set of rules before `fireAllRules()` when the list of eligible rules changes and update fact handle for drools to notice the change.

Comment: Can you please show me a simple piece of code that will help to execute it with spring boot

Comment: Its also helpful if you can help in something like configuring all the rule names in some configuration file like properties or yml files so that we can remove the rules names from that file and add rule names to that file so that only those rules get executed

Comment: @vinodchowdary Basically you pass the list of rules to execute into working memory (wrapped in this example by the `EligibleRules` object; as you can see this object has a list called "rules" defined, which contains the list from your yml config.)